# TensorFlow training shows very high loss

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am training a `DNNRegressor` with `label_dimension=7` and am getting very bad prediction values. I believe the root of the problem is that the training loss is being reported with values such as `3.4e+09`, `6.8e+08`, etc with these values not converging. I've made various adjustments to hyperparameters such as `num_layers`, `hidden_units`, etc but the prediction values are just garbage.

Here is some sample input:

```
f1       f2     f3    f4      f5    f6    f7   l1       l2       l3       l4       l5       l6       l7
39000.0  120.0  65.0  1000.0  25.0  0.69  3.94 39000.0  39959.0  42099.0  46153.0  49969.0  54127.0  55911.0
32000.0  185.0  65.0  1000.0  75.0  0.46  2.19 32000.0  37813.0  43074.0  48528.0  54273.0  60885.0  63810.0 
30000.0  185.0  65.0  1000.0  25.0  0.41  1.80 30000.0  32481.0  35409.0  39145.0  42750.0  46678.0  48595.0
```

Here, `f` columns are features and `l` columns are labels (i.e. prediction targets).

```
DNNRegressor(
    label_dimension=7,
    hidden_units=[64, 32],
    feature_columns=deep_cols,
    model_dir=model_dir,
    weight_column_name=None,
    optimizer=None, #defaults to Adagrad when None
    activation_fn=None, #defaults to relu when None
    config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_secs=60),
    feature_engineering_fn=None
)
```

Is my problem related to the init of `DNNRegressor` or is it most likely related to something else? I've ported the code from Google Cloud's Census example and it works well for the Census data but not for my data.

Comment: Try setting `clip_by_global_norm` parameter so that large updates are not happening due to outliers. Did you normalize the input data?

Comment: Yes the data is being normalized. I can't find the specification for `clip_by_global_norm` in `DNNRegressor`. Is there somewhere else that goes?

Comment: It is an optional argument to the constructor. It is called `gradient_clip_norm` https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNRegressor